# Subtract time from midnight in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I am using mysql and I have a column which tracks the datetime, in the form, yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss. I want to fetch that timestamp and calculate the difference of midnight to the time.

Example, if the datetime has 2014-11-22 13:53:41, I want the value of:
(Midnight of 2014-11-22) - (2014-11-22 13:53:41).

The value comes out to be: 11:07:19.

I want this value to be shown as counter on my website which uses php.

Comment: ,The value comes out to be: 13:53:41.. right? If not then please explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [TIMESTAMPDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) and [SEC_TO_TIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time)

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,  '2014-11-22 00:00:00',  '2014-11-22 13:53:41'))
```

Comment: I am not able to get it. I am using your answer in the following way: $time_left = TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,  '2014-11-22 00:00:00',  $rowMyReport["$taken_on"]);

Comment: try same script in MySQL first.. Is it work in MySQL?

Comment: also use SEC_TO_TIME function

Comment: @Roland: what version do you have? You did copy/paste this example, and it doesn't work?

Comment: @Roland, Hope you are using MySQL 5.6

Comment: @Glavic No my query looks like this: SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,  '2014-11-22 00:00:00',  'taken_on')) //'taken_on' is the name of the column

Comment: @Ronak I am using 5.1.73-cll

Comment: @Roland: `'taken_on'` is a string, not field name! Remove `'` or replace it with `\``.

Comment: @Glavic it's working. Thanks for helping me out here. It was a very careless mistake.

Comment: @Ronak I have to deal with this version since this is what is given to me. Anyways your suggestion worked. Thank you.